# Given remainders, determine smallest possible number of eggs in the basket

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have a question about "Elementary Number Theory - 6th Edition", written by David M.Burton.

In page 83 #9, I don't know how to solve it.
The problem is,

> The basket-of-eggs problem is often phrased in the following form: One egg remains when the eggs are removed from the basket 2,3,4,5, or 6 at a time; but, no eggs remain if they are removed 7 at a time. Find the smallest number of eggs that could have been in the basket.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 2):

This kind of has something to do with the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but the theorem only tells you that such a number (of eggs) exists. It doesn't tell you how to find the smallest such number.

To find that number, you need to look *inside the proof* of the CRT, and understand how the proof works well enough to actually find your number. It may be easier to solve the problem without using this "higher knowledge". I think it may be useful to solve your problem by hand *before* learning the CRT. It will make the CRT itself easier to grasp.

So, a direct solution. We need to find the smallest natural $N$ such that $N-1$ is divisible by each of $2, 3, 4, 5, 6$, and such that $N$ is divisible by $7$.

Let us look at the first condition separately. If $N-1$ is divisible by both $2$ and $3$, then it must be divisible by $6$. If it is divisible by $6$ and $4$, then it must also be divisible by $12$. It isn't hard to see that $N-1$ is in fact divisible by each of $2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ if and only if it is divisible by their least common multiple, which is $60$.

So, we reformulate the problem: find the smallest natural $N$ such that $N-1$ is a multiple of $60$, and $N$ is a multiple of $7$.

Now we can say that $N = 60k + 1$, $k$ is a nonnegative integer. You can just start trying candidates by hand: $60 \cdot 0 + 1 = 1$, $60 \cdot 1 + 1 = 61$, $60 \cdot 2 + 1 = 121$ and so on, until you encounter a multiple of $7$. I've done this by hand, and it happened at $k=5$: $N = 60 \cdot 5 + 1 = 301$. So here is your answer.

If you wonder whether there is a solution without trying numbers by hand, the answer is "kind-of yes".

Indeed, we need to solve the equation $$60 \cdot k + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 7.$$ Since $60 \equiv 4$ modulo $7$, this is equivalent to $$4 k \equiv -1 \mod 7.$$ Now we need to divide both sides by $4$. To divide by $4$ is the same as to multiply by its inverse, and the inverse of $4$ modulo $7$ is $2$, because $2 \cdot 4 \equiv 1 \mod 7$. So, we multiply by $2$ and see that $$k \equiv -2 \mod 7.$$ So $k$ itself has the form $k = 7t - 2$. Since our $k$ must be nonnegative, the smallest $k$ that fits is $k = 7-2 = 5$. And we come to the same answer: $N = 60 \cdot 5 + 1 = 301$.

Although in fact there was still some trial and error involved, because when I said that the inverse of $4$ modulo $7$ is $2$, I actually found it by hand. It can be done faster using Euclid's algorithm, but in this case it is cheaper to just try $4 \cdot 1, 4\cdot 2, 4 \cdot 3, \ldots$ and see immediately that $4 \cdot 2 \equiv 1 \mod 7$.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably expected to use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), since that is the main theorem covered in the previous few pages.

You know that $N \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ and $N \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, etc and finally $N \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$, then just use the CRT.

You might also look at the worked example of the use of the CRT that Burton gives a couple of pages before that exercise (page 86 in my edition of the book).

Comment: Yes, but are you sure the remainder is Chinese ?!

Comment: The remainder might not be, but the Theorem is Chinese, at least :)